# how to prevent user not to enter alphabets in input fied?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have one input field of mobile where user can enter his/her number , but currently user can enter alphabets in input field.I want user will only 
enter 10 digit number not alphapets.
here is my code

```
<section class="col-sm-12 bg-white  pl-20 pr-20">
  <div>

    <form novalidate [formGroup]="cfForm">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0">
          <label class="field-title mb-5">Mobile Number</label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" formControlName="mobile_no">
        </div>


    </form>
    {{cfForm.valid | json }}
    {{cfForm.value | json}}
  </div>
</section
```

TS file

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
     this.cfForm = this.fb.group({
          mobile_no: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{10}$')]],

    });
```

I don't want use type="number" or "text" .I want to use only "password" because i dont want to show my number to anyone
see code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfqkfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: why are you using type="password" for this? Why not type="text" (I wouldn't use number as that'd remove any leading zeros of your mobile number)

Comment: second thing i need to mask my phohe number that why I used type="password"

Comment: because I want to mask my phone number

Comment: Is your Angular validator not working?

Comment: @monty please suggest better solution

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfqkfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @user944513 Your code seems to be working fine. Please check the following stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfdb69?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.ts . It has a piece of code from your question only.

Comment: I am able to enter `alphabets`

Comment: @user944513 - So you want to prevent alphabets from getting entered? Currently it is marking the form as invalid.

Comment: yes .I don't want to eneter alphabets example "abc" only number is valid example "123"

Comment: @user944513 - Please check the answer below. The alphabets are now restricted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion, you can restrict alphabets from getting entered using the code of the key pressed.

Refer to the below code:-

**.ts**:-

```
  validateNumber(event) {
    const keyCode = event.keyCode;

    const excludedKeys = [8, 37, 39, 46];

    if (!((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
      (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) ||
      (excludedKeys.includes(keyCode)))) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

**HTML**:-

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" formControlName="mobile_no" (keydown)="validateNumber($event)">
```

[You can refer to the stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfdb69?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

Add `type="number"` to your `input` element, that should automatically trigger the number pad rather than the regular keyboard on most devices.

Comment: I am not running this application on mobile .I am running on web

Comment: second thing i need to mask my phohe number that why I used type="password"

Comment: this would not solve the problem and would remove leading zeros and it seems they want the number masked. the issue is that the validator doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @monty please suggest better solution

Comment: Ah right, I misunderstood the question then. Check out one of the other answers using the pattern attribute.

Comment: The downside with that is, later on, you can not add commas to price inputs which are also number inputs. You can use `inputmode=numeric` for mobile devices to bring up a number-only keyboard, but for desktop I think we should check it with code inside handleChange.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5, You could use the common attribute `pattern`.

*(And also `inputmode` in some browsers)*

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

A regex pattern to force 10 digits: `^[0-9]{10}$`

Example:

```html
<form action="javascript: alert('alright');">
<div>
  <input type="password" 
         pattern="^[0-9]{10}$"
         minlength="10" maxlength="10"
         placeholder="Enter Mobile no"
         required title="Ten digits required.">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: or perhaps in ts file specify pattern
mobilepattern = '^[0-9]{10}$' then just use that in the pattern directive. At the moment your solution doesn't limit it to 10 chars.

Comment: not working please share stackblitz link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfqkfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: please share your stackblitz link

Comment: inputmode is not supported by firefox and safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Comment: @RahulDudhane Okay, I removed it. Not that it would cause problems though, those browsers would just ignore the option.

Answer (score 1):

firstly you can add `maxlength` attribute to your input field, that will allow only 10 characters to be passed. Like this below:

Now for only Numeric characters validation, i suggest you should create a directive and use that directive in all the places, where you need Numbers only validation.

.html

```
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="cfForm">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0">
          <label class="field-title mb-5">Mobile Number</label>
          <input NumbersOnly="true" type="password" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" formControlName="mobile_no" maxlength="10">
        </div>


    </form>
    {{cfForm.valid | json }}
    {{cfForm.value | json}}
  </div>
</section>
```

NumbersOnly.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[NumbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

 constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

 @Input() NumbersOnly: boolean;


 @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
 let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
 if (this.NumbersOnly) {
  if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+C
    (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+V
    // (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+X
    (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
}
```

Like this way you can achieve what you desire. 
The main advantage of using this approch is that, in your whole project , whereever you need Number Only validation, you can simple add `NumbersOnly = true` inside the input field, and it will handle the rest.

Visit this to know more about [Directives](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive).

Answer (score 0):

use `preventDefault()` method and regex 
**HTML**

```
 <input type="password" (keypress)="matcher($event)"
    placeholder="Enter Mobile no" formControlName="mobile_no">
```

Component:

```
 public matcher(event) {
        const allowedRegex = /[0-9]/g;

        if (!event.key.match(allowedRegex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event to check whether the input is Number or Alphabet .
Just add the event in input field

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" formControlName="mobile_no" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
```

In the TS file

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {
const charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```

}